# Inserting a Python variable inside html generated by Qt Designer (PyQt5)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

So, I've used Qt Designer to generate a basic framework of a GUI for a program I've been developing in Python. I've been working through adding all of my functionality and logic into it. So far, so good. I've made a method that should, when a rocket is selected from the QlistWidget on the left, pull information from a dictionary and populate it into the QTextBrowser in the center, using the text generated from a block of HTML as a template. What I'm trying to accomplish at this moment is to be able to use my Python variables inside the chunk of generated HTML that currently populates the QTextBrowser. I have tried several methods, all of which have angered my IDE. I figure that if I can make it work with the title, I can figure out the rest. So, I am asking your help in figuring out how to accomplish this. I have read everything I can find about this and more generalized versions of doing this, but nothing has worked so far. I was able to make this all work in Tkinter, but decided to refactor into PyQt as it is a lot more modern-looking, but comes with the caveat of being a lot more complicated.

I have appended the codeblock in question, but producing a minimal reproducible example would be huge and honestly, outside of the scope of the question. Sorry about that.

I have tried:

- replacing "ROCKET" with %s and appending % rocketName to the end of the HTML block
- replacing "ROCKET" with {rocketName} and adding .format(rocketName=rocketName) to the end of the HTML
- f"html html html"{rocketName}"html html html"
- "html html html" + rocketName + "html html html"
- "html html html" + str(rocketName) + "html html html"

I've been stuck on this for hours. Any insight would be very appreciated.

```
# ***** Define what happens when a rocket is selected from listWidget ******
    def selectionChanged(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        rocketName = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:9.75pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:18pt; font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;\">ROCKET</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Agency:</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Manufacturer:</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Payload Capacity to LEO: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Height: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Diameter: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Mass: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Years in Operation: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Country: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Operational Status: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Number of Stages: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Burn Time: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Thrust: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">ISP: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Cost Per Launch: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Fuel Type: </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Arial, sans-serif\'; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:transparent;\">Additional Information:</span></p></body></html>"))
```

Comment: Using formatted strings should work just fine. What errors are you getting when trying any of the methods you describe?

Comment: @Heike You were right, it did work! Apparently I was placing the "f" at the beginning of the whole html code block rather than the specific line. I didn't realize that those were all separate lines as they had no commas in them- a first for me. Thanks for trying to help, though!

Answer (score 0):

When using f string literals in HTML when that HTML itself is inside of Python, be sure to take note that commas are not needed between the blocks of HTML. Because of that, the "f" should be placed at the beginning of the specific block of code rather than the entire block of HTML.